# Accesing .accdb linked to sharepoint lists in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, ucanaccess

I need to connect to a .accdb file with java. Inside of this file, there are some sharepoint lists I need to research.

I am using Spring Boot and UCanAccess to make the connection into the .accdb.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ucanaccess</groupId>
    <artifactId>ucanaccess</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

It doesn't seem to be any problem on the following code, because it enters on the if...

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://SHAREPOINT_COMUN.accdb;memory=false", user, password);
if (conn != null) {
     log.info("URL de conexión: " + conn.getMetaData().getURL());

     conn.close();
} else {
     log.error("No se ha conectado a la base de datos.");
}
```

But, when I try to look into any of the lists with:

```
stmt = conn.createStatement();
rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM <table_name>");

while (rs.next()) {
     String tableName = rs.getString("Name");
     log.info("Tabla: " + tableName);
}
```

It throws me the following exception:

`net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::5.0.1 user does not have sufficient privileges or object not found: <table_name>`

I have enough privileges because with Access I am able to see it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: _user does not have sufficient privileges_ seems pretty clear to me. Looks like the problem is not with your code.

Comment: @Abra but on Access I can enter the table with the same user and password and look to the info corretly, so my user should have privileges.